# Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from NaN total entries)

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables version 1.10.12. Below is my relevant code

```
// initialize datatable
jQuery('#taskTable').DataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bLengthChange":false,
    "pageLength": 10,
    "sAjaxDataProp":"serverPageDataModelBean.data" 
});
```

Data is being displayed and pagination is working. However when I set `"bInfo": true` I get the following message:

> Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from NaN total entries)

and my Next button does not work. In serverPageDataModelBean I am sending `{"recordsTotal":12,"recordsFiltered":12,"data":[]}` where data is not empty.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 19):

I know this too late, but I'm posting this in case someone stumbles on this. 
The answer is you need to set serverside to false like this "serverSide": false.

Comment: Thank You !!

Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Mamadou Barry what if I am fetting the data from the ajax call from backend, If I make serverside false or remove then no data shows

Answer (score 12):

#### CAUSE

Your server-side response is missing `draw` parameter which should have the same value as the `draw` parameter in the request. When that happens, jQuery DataTables discards the data.

> `draw`
>
> The draw counter that this object is a response to - from the `draw` parameter sent as part of the data request.

#### SOLUTION

Return `draw` parameter with the same value as `draw` parameter from the request.

#### LINKS

See [Server-side processing - Returned data](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) for more information.

Comment: I know this is too late. But how can we do that?

Comment: @Saitama A simple JSON response data the client's AJAX call will receive, containing the parameters of type `Number`: `draw`, `recordsFiltered`, and `recordsTotal`, should suffice.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `serverside: true` option, then remove this or write `serverside: false`

for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example1').dataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "view_results",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        'order':[]
    } );
});
```

Answer (score 4):

the response for empty data when handling on server side for example php will be ...

```
echo json_encode(
        array(
        'draw' => $_POST['draw'],
        'data' => [],
        'recordsFiltered' =>  0,
        'recordsTotal' => 0
        )
     );
```

In pure json

```
{"draw":1,"data":[],"recordsFiltered":0,"recordsTotal":0}
```

In short no matter what Datatable as on 2020 needs this parameters on server side handling.

Answer (score 0):

removing the serverSide attribute(or making it false) is not the right solution. This would break if you have pagination set to true and the sitewide pagination is controlling your data being displayed. If you dont have any such customisation then off-the-shelf pagination by jQuery will do the job.

The solution taht shall work all time is setting the 'draw' attribute in the json returned by your servercall.

I can provide an example from Coldfusion perspective. the idea is the same. ensure the json you return back to the server is having the 'draw' parameter added.

```
  <cfquery name="qryItemList" datasource="#session.dbsource#">
    SELECT  item 1,
            item 2,
            COUNT(*) OVER () as TotalCount
    FROM  Items 
  </cfquery>
  <cfif len(qryItemList.TotalCount) NEQ 0>
    <cfset Total= qryItemList.TotalCount>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset Total= 0>
  </cfif>
  <cfset dataset = queryToStruct(qryItemList)> //queryToStruct is a UDF to convert an entire query to a struct
  <cfset dataset = serializejson(dataset)>

  <cfset dataset = ReplaceNoCase(dataset,'"recordcount":#qryItemList.recordcount#','"recordsTotal":#Total#,"recordsFiltered":#Total#, "draw":"0"')>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried `serverside: false` but it didn't work, also make sure to check that the variables in ajax use proper camelCase, i.e. a captital `T` in recordsTotal and a capital `F` in recordsFiltered. It should be like below:

```
$output = array(
    'data'=>$data,
    'draw'=>$_POST['draw'],
    'recordsTotal'=>$filtered_rows,
    'recordsFiltered'=>$countrow,
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make **"serverSide": false** or remove the line.
but make sure that making "serverSide": false will be okay for short data tables
For larger ones, it won't support or not suggested